# Recurring line disappearance, issue with while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

*I'm new to python, so be gentle...

Overall issue: I have had an issue in multiple codes I've written lately where lines get skipped and it is obviously an error on my part. I know I must be messing up ordering of something, but I'm just not seeing it. My most recent issue can be found here: [Is there any reason Python would skip a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54918927/is-there-any-reason-python-would-skip-a-line)

Now, I want to write an application to pre-sell a limited number of tickets. Here are the conditions:

"Each buyer can buy as many as 4 tickets. There are a total of 15 tickets that are available to pre-sell. The program should prompt the user for the amount of tickets they want to purchase and then display the number of remaining tickets. Repeat until all tickets have been sold, and then display the total number of buyers."

A similar problem is occurring.

```
buy = int()
ticket_num = 15
buyers = 0

while ticket_num > 0:
    buy = int(input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? "))
    if buy > 4:
        print("You cannot buy that many (4 max).")
        buy = input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? ")
    else:
        ticket_num = ticket_num - buy
        print("There are currently", ticket_num, "remaining.")
        buyers = buyers + 1

print() 

print("The total number of buyers was:", buyers)
```

It appears that the print line in the 'else' structure is not being read and I don't quite understand why...

Can anyone lend me any insight into what my overall misunderstanding is..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a couple of things incorrect with this problem:

- I did not have enough conditional statements (elif) to cover the requirements
- I did not need to have the buy variable gather input again in the if statement because the while loop would already cause the program to prompt for input again.
- I did not need to have the buy variable outside the while loop at all, I just had to initialize it before using it in the 'if' statement.

The solution is as follows:

```
tickets = 15
buyers = 0
print("There are currently", tickets, "tickets available.")

while tickets > 0 :
    buy = int(input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? "))
    if buy <= 4 and tickets - buy >= 0:
        tickets = tickets - buy
        buyers = buyers + 1
        print("There are", tickets, "tickets remaining.")
    elif buy > 4:
        print("You cannot buy that many (4 max).")
    elif tickets - buy < 0:
        print("You can only buy what remains. Please see previous 'remaining' message.")

print()
print("There was a total of", buyers, "buyers.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buy = int()
ticket_num = 15
buyers = 0

while ticket_num > 0:
    buy = int(input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? "))
    if buy > 4:
        print("You cannot buy that many (4 max).")
        #buy = input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? ")
    else:
        if ticket_num - buy>=0:
            ticket_num = ticket_num - buy
            print("There are currently", ticket_num, "remaining.")
            buyers = buyers + 1
        else:
            print("There are currently", ticket_num, "remaining. You can buy up to", ticket_num, "tickets")
print()

print("The total number of buyers was:", buyers)
```

Here is the solution. Problem was you were getting input two times. Firstly below the while. Secondly below at the if statement.